# How can I statically validate a Spring context file?

Tags: spring

Is there a tool to spot at least the most obvious and egregious errors that Spring context files can have like "this referenced property file does not exist", "there is no property file defining this value", "there are multiple beans for this autowired dependency" or "there is no such class" *before* launching it and having your program explode on the first such issue?

Comment: Write a unit test that loads it the same way your program does?

Comment: @JBNizet That might be trivial if my program wasn't being loaded at run time a generic Liferay portlet that downloads additional context files from a database and then finally loads "my program." Again, however, my case is pretty special so I will welcome answers that are useful in the generic case.